# data is not getting saved in mongoose database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save  my mongoDB with mongoose.app.post function calls the saveLogInfo function. The problem in saveLogInfo function is  the code till 
consoel.log ("inside savae") 
is runnig but after that I got an error that 
string is not a function
callback in not getting called and show an error that "saving failed."

the schema is:
    var LoginInfoSchema=new Schema({

```
username:String,
password:String
```

});

app.post function:

var LoginInfo=db.model('LoginInfo',LoginInfoSchema);

```
function saveLogInfo (username , password ,callback){
console.log("saveLogInfo CALLED");
var receivedObj = new LoginInfo({
    username:username ,
    password:password
});
console.log(receivedObj);
receivedObj.save(function(err , data){
    console.log("inside Save "); 
    if(err){
        //res.send(err);
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        callback();   // the error is here
    }
});
```

}

please guide me what is the error in this function

Comment: What does your call to `saveLogInfo` and the LoginInfo schema look like?

Comment: schema is :var LoginInfoSchema=new Schema({

    username:String,
    password:String
});
var LoginInfo=db.model('LoginInfo',LoginInfoSchema);

Comment: @JohnnyHK.....thanks for trying to resolve my problem but now  I have fixed my problem. thank God my code is runnig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `callback` parameter that is being passed in when you call the `saveLogInfo` function is a string rather than a function.  Could you post the code that is calling `saveLogInfo`?

It is possible that when you call `saveLogInfo`, you are passing in the name of a function as the `callback` parameter, but are mistakenly wrapping it in quotes.